# Is it possible to import OpenCover /result in SonarQube?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sonarqube, opencover

I'm currently changing things to our Sonar setup since Gallio isn't supported anymore by C# Ecosystem 3. I already successfully imported the unit test coverage by using OpenCover with following command.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -register -target:"c:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console-x86.exe" -targetargs:"d:\Sonar\MyTest.dll /noshadow /framework=net-4.0" -output:"d:\Deploy\Sonar\Coverage.xml" "-filter:+[*]* -[*]Test"
```

With this command I'm only getting the Unit Test Coverage but I would also like to see the number of failed and successful tests. I think I can achieve this with the /result option like

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -register -target:"c:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console-x86.exe" -targetargs:"d:\Deploy\Sonar\MyTest.dll /noshadow /framework=net-4.0 /result=tests.xml"
```

This command returns an xml with information about the tests that ran but is there any way to import this xml into SonarQube? Or isn't this supported?

Currently I'm importing the Coverage.xml file with the following command:

```
sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=D:/Deploy/Sonar/Coverage.xml
```

Is there a similar property to import the tests.xml file with the test results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the following site http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/07/19/integrate-nunit-test-into-a-tfs-build/ I was able to convert the output of OpenCover test results to a .trx format using an XSLT transformation. After the transformation I just used the default import functionality

```
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=MyTestRestultFile.trx
```

Answer (score 8):

OpenCover is now officially supported by SonarQube, please see the [SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770#CodeCoverageResultsImport(C#,VB.NET)-OpenCover). You can pass the location of the XML report OpenCover generated with the command line parameter

```
/d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="%path%\%report_file%"
```

where `%path%` is the folder your report file is generated in and `%report_file%` is the file name of your OpenCover XML report.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugin, it looks like you can import unit test execution reports of MSTest format only.